# STR_TO_DATE not working with the node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, date

When I am tring to run the following query in mysql

```
  select STR_TO_DATE(m.plan_start_date,'%Y-%m-%d') as plan_start_date from MemberDetails m ;
```

It is working as expected but when I am running the same using node js as

```
         return dbConnection.query("select STR_TO_DATE(m.plan_start_date,'%Y-%m-%d') as plan_start_date from MemberDetails m ",callback);
```

But then it is returning as the data present in db. Like that

```
{
    "status": true,
    "members": [
        {
            "plan_start_date": "2017-12-27T18:30:00.000Z"
        }

    ]
}
```

It is sending the data in different format and sending date as string instead of date.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "perb",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "cors": "2.8.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.15.5",
    "forever-monitor": "^1.7.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "moment": "2.19.3",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "multer": "1.3.0",
    "mysql2": "1.5.0",
    "path": "0.12.7",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "request": "2.83.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5"
  }
}
```

npm version: 5.5.1
node: v8.9.1

Comment: If you try something link `STR_TO_DATE(m.plan_start_date,'%Y-%m-%d') as plan_start_date2`, does property `plan_start_date2` contain what you expect?

Comment: what is the data type of plan_start_date ?

Comment: plan_start_date type is datetime. @JeanDoux

Comment: @FrostyZ still same result

Comment: then you are trying to convert a datetime to a date with str_to_date, do you see the problem ?

Comment: my plan_start_date is text type and str_to_date working fine in mysql workbench but giving same error as above in node.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the right function as plan_start_date is datetime you should use DATE_FORMAT :

```
  SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(m.plan_start_date,'%Y-%m-%d') as plan_start_date
  FROM MemberDetails m ;
```

If you want a date and not a datetime, you can use the function date :

```
  SELECT  DATE(m.plan_start_date) as plan_start_date
  FROM MemberDetails m ;
```

Comment: now the format is changed but it is still returning the date as the string